# Move variables in global environment to a dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

How to save multiple variables in global environment into a dataframe in R? I can do it one by one using the $. But is there a command that moves all variables at once?

Comment: *All* variables? What if they aren't all vectors of the same length? (If there are just a few variables, you can do `data.frame(cbind(x, y, z))` to create a data frame of x, y, and z).

Comment: Eww.. Please, please stop telling newbies to use the form `data.frame(cbind(...)))`. It will coerce any numeric or factor variables to something that the naive user does not expect. take a look at the output of `cbind(factor(letters[1:5]), letters[1:5], 1:5)`.

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
do.call(data.frame, lapply(ls(), get))
```

But let me just say this sounds like a **horrible** idea.

Comment: +1 for an answer but mostly for saying this sounds like a  horrible idea.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a named list of objects, then:

```
 cbind(dfrm, list.obj)
```

E.g.

```
dados <- data.frame(x=1:10, v1=rnorm(10), v2=rnorm(10))
dat1 <- rnorm(10)
dat2 <- letters[1:5]
cbind(dados, list(new1=dat1, new2=dat2))
```

Can also use this form:

```
cbind(dados, new1=dat1, new2=dat2)
```

If you had a bunch of variables in the global environment with the character string "zzz" in their names and you wanted to append them columnwise to an existing dataframe, you could use this:

```
dados[, ls(patt="zzz") ] <- sapply( ls(patt="zzz"), get)
```

You might notice that I was objecting to using `data.frame(cbind(...))` and yet I am saying to use `cbind`. Well, I am assuming  that the first argument in my case is already a dataframe, so that `cbind` does not get called, but rather `cbind.data.frame' gets called, and it will allow the usual list-behavior of data.frame objects to persist. If the first argument is only a vector, then`.Internal(cbind(...)` will do coercion to a matrix which will remove attributes of all the arguments and coerce then into a common storage mode.